# Remove words from an exclude list in each row of a pandas.Series

Tags: python, performance, numpy, pandas

I am trying to remove all occurrences of the words I collect in the list `exclude` from every text note. This is my approach.

```
import operator,re

exclude=[]
for i in range(len(freq_select)):
  if freq_select[i][1]<=25:
    exclude.append(freq_select[i][0])



def remove_nonfrequent(note):
  print(remove_nonfrequent.i)
  sentences=[]
  for sent in note.split('.'):
    words=sent.split(' ')
    #print("Before:",len(words))
    for word in words:
      for j in exclude:
        if j==word:
          #print(j,word)
          words.remove(word)
    #print("After:",len(words))
    sent=' '.join(words)
    sentences.append(sent)
  note='. '.join(sentences)
  remove_nonfrequent.i+=1
  return '. '.join([i for i in note.split('.') if i!=''])



remove_nonfrequent.i=0
jdf.NOTES=jdf.NOTES.apply(remove_nonfrequent)
```

I was initially looping over all the notes in pandas series. But now I am using `apply()` and I can say performance increased little bit. But it still takes a very long time.

Each note in the `pandas.Series` is of variable length. However, an average note can contain somewhere between 3000-6000 words. One note even has 13000 words.

I would like to get some help in this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You currently have to loop over all exclude words to check if it is equal to the current word. If your `exclude` was a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-set), you could just do `if j in exclude`. This change alone should speed up your code a lot (how much depends on how large your list of exclude words actually is).

In addition, you could simplify getting the exclude words:

```
from collections import Counter
form itertools import takewhile

THRESHOLD = 25

words = Counter(whatever_generates_your_words())
exclude = set(t[0] for t in takewhile(lambda t: t[1] <= THRESHOLD,
                                      reversed(words.most_common())))
```

This uses the fact that [`collections.Counter.most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) is sorted by frequency, so reversing it starts with the least common words. [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) stops taking when the condition is no longer true, so you don't need to go through all words in the `Counter`.

For the filtering you should probably use some [list comprehensions](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python). All three of the following functions are doing the same thing:

```
from itertools import filterfalse

def remove_nonfrequent(note):
    sentences = []
    for sentence in note.split('. '):
        sentence_ = []
        for word in sentence:
            if word not in exclude:
                sentence_.append(word)
        if sentence:
            sentences.append(" ".join(sentence))
    return ". ".join(sentences)

def remove_nonfrequent(note):
    return ". ".join(" ".join(filterfalse(exclude.__contains__,
                              sentence.split(" ")))
                     for sentence in note.split('. '))
                     if sentence)

def remove_nonfrequent(note):        
    return ". ".join(" ".join(word for word in sentence.split(" ")
                              if word not in exclude)
                     for sentence in note.split('. ') if sentence)
```

I personally prefer the last one, as it is the most readable one to me.

Note that Python has an official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which recommends using 4 spaces as indentation and surrounding operators with spaces.

---

Since you are using this function with `pandas` later, a different approach might actually be faster. There is a [`pd.Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) method that can take a dictionary of replacements. You can use it like this:

```
from itertools import repeat

replacements = dict(zip((fr'\b{word}\b' for word in exclude), repeat("")))
df.NOTES.replace(replacements, regex=True, inplace=True)
df.NOTES.replace({r' +': ' ', r' +\.': '.'}, regex=True, inplace=True)
```

The first replace does all the word replacements (using `\b` to ensure only complete words are replaced), while the latter one fixes multiple spaces and spaces before a period.

Comment: Is there any way i can track how much of the execution is done instead of a blank output? i cannot insert print statements in one liners right?

Comment: @AdityaVartak: You can just re-insert your debug statements before the line with the `return`. Or save the output in a variable, do something else and then return it.

Comment: This works like charm. Thanks @Graipher

Comment: @AdityaVartak: I added a more vectorized version that might be even faster.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but for now the original answer would suffice. Would use this if more optimization is needed.

Comment: @AdityaVartak: Fair enough. I just couldn't leave it be without also including a `pandas` version :). Which is also a lot shorter and could be encapsulated into its own function.